# GDebi Package Installer not launching, and won't install .deb files on the ~/Desktop 18.10

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 18.10, gdebi

This morning I discovered that I can't launch GDebi. When I try to launch it from the SUPER menu, it puts its name in the top bar with a spinning cursor, stays there for about 10 seconds, and then disappears.

When I type `sudo -H gdebi-gtk` in the terminal, it launches fine.

Here's the desktop file...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GDebi Package Installer
GenericName=Package Installer
Comment=Install and view software packages
Exec=sudo -H gdebi-gtk %f
Icon=gnome-mime-application-x-deb
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=System;
MimeType=application/vnd.debian.binary-package;
NotShowIn=KDE;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gdebi
StartupNotify=true
Keywords=package;apt;dpkg;install
```

Here's some file info...

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ll gdebi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Dec 31  2017 gdebi -> ../share/gdebi/gdebi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Dec 31  2017 gdebi-gtk -> ../share/gdebi/gdebi-gtk*

$ ll /usr/share/gdebi
total 104K
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jun 12 13:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 527 root root  20K Oct 19 10:35 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4.0K Dec 31  2017 gdebi*
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jun 12 14:04 GDebi/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 3.5K Dec 31  2017 gdebi-gtk*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 4.2K Feb 25  2010 gdebi.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  60K Jul  2  2015 gdebi.ui
```

Any idea why gdebi won't launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can understand the installed `/usr/share/applications/gdebi.desktop` differs from your file:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gdebi.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GDebi Package Installer
GenericName=Package Installer
Comment=Install and view software packages
Exec=gdebi-gtk %f
Icon=gnome-mime-application-x-deb
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=System;
MimeType=application/vnd.debian.binary-package;
NotShowIn=KDE;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gdebi
StartupNotify=true
Keywords=package;apt;dpkg;install
```

It uses PolicyKit's pkexec to be ran as `root`:

```
$ dpkg -L gdebi | grep policy
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.pkexec.gdebi-gtk.policy
```

So you should not use `sudo` for it.

I have just tested on my Ubuntu 18.10 VM - I can install manually downloaded deb-file:

```
apt-get download meld
gdebi-gtk meld*.deb
```

above I entered password and got Meld installed.

So consider to remove your self-made desktop file and reinstall the application with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdebi gdebi-core
```

---

Also you can try to reinstall PolicyKit-related components:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall policykit-1 python3-apt
```

---

I have checked your discovery about installation of deb-file from `~/Desktop` folder.

And guess what?
I can confirm this issue on clean Ubuntu 18.10 installation. It is unbelievable.
I'm completely can not understand the modern GNOME philosophy.
But by the way I have reported [bug 1807761 against `nautilus-desktop`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1807761) executable (as it controls the desktop in 18.10) (and to upstream [as bug 782](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/782)) to help other users.

On upstream the bug [is closed with comment](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/782#note_382586):

> *António Fernandes* commented:
>
> > Thanks for taking the time to report this.
> >
> > Thay version of nautilus is no longer supported upstream, and nautilus-desktop is absent from the latest version (a shell extension is available as replacement).
> >
> > So, a bug fix is not expectable from this side.

**Conclusion: on modern GNOME you can't install deb-files from desktop. This will not be fixed in 18.10. And it is completely unpredictable what will be prohibited next time in 19.04.**

**Update: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is affected too.**

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I do remember adding `sudo -H` in the Exec= line because gdebi hadn't been asking for user password when double-clicking on .deb files (when gdebi is set as the default app for .deb files). Since reinstalling, I wonder if that problem returns...

Comment: Actually, it didn't ask for user password when I clicked the install button.

Comment: Possible Wayland issue or [something similar](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313). On MATE running on top of Xorg it works as expected.

Comment: Thank goodness I'm not running any Wayland stuff, as far as I know. So, I just retried gdebi, and sure enough, when I double-click on a .deb file, gdebi launches, I click the `Install Package` button, and where it should ask for user password, it just quits gdebi. However, if I launch gdebi first, then open the .deb file, click the `Install Package` button, it all works as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: And, I just tried `gdebi-gtk filename.deb` in the `terminal`, and it all worked fine too. So, just when double-clicking on a .deb file does it not work.

Comment: Just checked double-clicking from Caja (and open with too) without any issues. You may want to check your file associations in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: Hum, with `grep gdebi mimeapps.list` I see gdebi listed twice, as `application/x-deb=gdebi.desktop` and `application/x-deb=gdebi.desktop;`.

Comment: Changing mimeapps.list didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Fresh idea - what if this is caused by policykit or python-apt (GDebi dependencies)? Try to reinstall them with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall policykit-1 python3-apt`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional idea. I did reinstall policykit-1 and python3-apt, rebooted, but it didn't solve the problem. Here's maybe another clue... in terminal, I type `gdebi-gtk filename.deb` and it works fine! It asks for my password as it should after I click the install button. It seems to fail when starting from the .deb file on my desktop. I works the same from another user account.

Comment: Oh oh oh... fresh clue! The problem with gdebi-gtk occurs when trying to install a .deb file on my Desktop. However, if I move that same .deb into a fresh new folder on my Desktop, or into my Downloads folder, gdebi-gtk works fine! I removed all other files from my Desktop, thinking that one of them may have been causing the problem, but that's not it. So... the problem occurs when .deb files are on the Desktop.

Comment: @heynnema it is unbelievable, I can confirm  your issue with deb-file on Desktop. I reported bugs to launchpad and upstream. Upcoming 19.04 is affected too.

Comment: Thank goodness! I'm not crazy. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

Go figure... reinstalling `gdebi` and `gdebi-core` fixed the launch problem. But the original problem remains.

**Update #1:**

So, now I recall... I previously had a problem where if gdebi is set as the default app for .deb files, when double-clicking on a .deb file, gdebi would open, and when I clicked on the `Install Package` button, where it should have asked for my user password, it just quit instead.

However, if I started gdebi first, and opened the .deb file manually, then clicked `Install Package`, it would properly ask for my user password, and would install the .deb file as expected.

My previous fix was to modify the .desktop file's Exec= line from:

`Exec=gdebi-gtk %f`

to

`Exec=sudo -H gdebi-gtk %f`

The reinstall undid that fix, cured the launch problem, but the user password and quit problem is back.

**Update #2:**

I reinstalled `policykit-1` and `python3-apt` at the suggestion of @NOrbert. No joy.

**Update #3:**

Oh oh oh... fresh clue! The problem with gdebi-gtk occurs when trying to install a .deb file on my Desktop. However, if I move that same .deb into a fresh new folder on my Desktop, or into my Downloads folder, gdebi-gtk works fine!

@NOrbert has confirmed the problem.